# How make line break when working with Xelement

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, xelement, xmlwriter

Hello and sorry if question is strange and sorry for bad english.
My code:

```
xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws))
{
    string lb = "\r\n";
    XElement I11 = new XElement("I11", lb,
                                new XElement("I11_TIPAS", "2"), lb,
                                new XElement("I11_PAV", "pav"), lb,
                                new XElement("I11_KODAS_IS", "985"), lb,
                                from iseip in eip
                                select new XElement("I12", lb,
              new XElement("DI12_BAR_KODAS", iseip.DI12_BAR_KODAS), lb,
              new XElement("I12_KODAS_SS", iseip.I12_KODAS_SS), lb,
              new XElement("I12_KIEKIS", iseip.I12_KIEKIS), lb,
              new XElement("I12_FRAKCIJA", iseip.I12_FRAKCIJA), lb), lb
        );
    I11.Save(xw);
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("bbb.eip", sb.ToString());
```

Output:

[image: output]

Need get like this:

[image: need like this]

Problem every I12 node must be in new line. Where is problem?

Comment: You are missing : xws.Indent = true;

Comment: add to code xws.Indent = true; same result

Comment: spending on this problem 3 days and no success. Please help.

Comment: Remove the lb. The Indent = true will do automatically, and your lb may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: lb removed, node I11_KODAS_IS and all other nodes become in one line. Removing lb results worst

Comment: i think because this is not actual xml and i using xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true; maybe xws.Indent = true have no power in this situacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
            XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            xws.Indent = true;
            List<EIP> eip = new List<EIP>();
            using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create("bbb.eip", xws))
            {
                XElement I11 = new XElement("I11", new object[] {
                                            new XElement("I11_TIPAS", "2"),
                                            new XElement("I11_PAV", "pav"),
                                            new XElement("I11_KODAS_IS", "985")
                });
                foreach(var iseip in eip)
                {

                    XElement I12 = new XElement("I12", new object[] {
                          new XElement("DI12_BAR_KODAS", iseip.DI12_BAR_KODAS),
                          new XElement("I12_KODAS_SS", iseip.I12_KODAS_SS),
                          new XElement("I12_KIEKIS", iseip.I12_KIEKIS),
                          new XElement("I12_FRAKCIJA", iseip.I12_FRAKCIJA)
                    });
                    I11.Add(I12);

                }
                I11.Save(xw);
            }
 
        }
        public class EIP
        {
            public string DI12_BAR_KODAS { get;set;}
            public string I12_KODAS_SS { get;set;}
            public string I12_KIEKIS { get;set;}
            public string I12_FRAKCIJA { get;set;}
                         
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
        xmlDocument.Save(@"D:\\Code2Try\bbb.eip");
```

XMLDocument saves in proper format.